# increment and decrement button like the stepper swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to increment the value of the text field. I am getting an error.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nbre: UILabel!

    @IBAction func incrementer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        nbre.text = Int(nbre.text) + 1
    }
```

The problem I have is to increment the original value of the textfield by 1. When I do it I have this message:

> "Value of optional type 'String?'"

Comment: 1. Post code as text, not pictures. 2. There's no error in the picture. 3. Post the complete and exact error, as text, in your question.

Comment: First off, you need to show some research effort. Second, please post code as code and not as an image, and third, tell us the error, how are we supposed to know the error??? Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is very low quality, my best guess is that the label's text is not force unwrapped, which is what the error is saying. Simply add a `!`after `nbre.text`:

```
nbre.text = Int(nbre.text!) + 1
```

You also need to convert the `Int` back to a `String`:

```
nbre.text = String(Int(nbre.text!)! + 1)
```

Comment: same problem even with the new "nbre.text = String(Int(nbre.text) + 1)"

Comment: @ElyasBennani Did you try `nbre.text = String(Int(nbre.text!)! + 1)`?

Comment: This will crash if the label doesn't have any text.

Comment: @rmaddy True, but in OP's case, the label is guaranteed to have text.

Comment: @rmaddy When the OP originally had an image in his post, the label had "1" as its text.

Comment: @Xcoder it worked, can you explain me what are the "!" for?

Comment: @ElyasBennani Glad to know that it worked. There are two "!" in the answer. The first one it to force unwrap your label's text, because there could be nothing there. However, in this case, there must be text, since you have an initial text value. The second "!" is to force unwrap the `Int` conversion from `String`, which can result in a `nil` value because not all strings have only numbers in them. Sorry if my explanation was a bit confusing, you can check [this blog](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/impliticly-vs-force-unwrapping-swift-optionals/) or do your own research to learn more.

Comment: The `!` is a "force unwrap` operator. I call it the "crash if nil" operator. Until you understand `Optionals` **really** well you should avoid using force-unwrapping, since it will cause your program to crash if the optional contains nil. rmaddy's answer is **much** better than this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the mentioned code and found:

> Value of optional type 'String?'

You should unwrap the value by putting exclamation mark but this may lead to a crash if label does not hold the value. So better we check for value first with `if-let` -> `Increment` -> `assign to label`

```
@IBOutlet var nbre: UILabel!

@IBAction func incrementor(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = nbre.text, let number = Int(text) {
        nbre.text = String(number + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: did not help me,get another error   "type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: This will crash if the label doesn't have any text.

Comment: Are you having `+1` as a text or only `1`?

Comment: @ElyasBennani, Please check now. Considering label holds an integer value at initial. say `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is because the `text` property of `UILabel` is an optional String and the `Int` initializer expects a non-optional `String`. And then you try to assign the resulting `Int` value to the `text` property. You can't assign an `Int` value to a `String` property.

But there is a bigger issue here. You are mistakenly using a label as a source of data to keep track of a counter. That's a poor design.

The proper solution is to have an actual `Int` property that keeps track of the current count. Then set the label's `text` to the value of this count property.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nbre: UILabel!

    var count = 0

    @IBAction func incrementer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        count += 1
        nbre.text = "\(count)"
    }
```

And most likely in `viewDidLoad` you need to set the initial value of the label:

```
nbre.text = "\(count)"
```

Comment: adding a new variable costing memory it's better to use the text inside the label directly if it's guaranteed to initially have value

Comment: @Sh_Khan No. Views are not for storing data. It is much better to use a proper property to store data. Views should only show data. And if you are worried about the memory of a single `Int` property you have much bigger problems.

Comment: Listen to rmaddy. He speaks truth. It is a bad idea to use a view object to save state data. rmaddy, one minor change I would suggest is to add a `didSet` on the `count` property, and set the label's text in the didSet. The the iBaction can simply increment/decrement the count.